# Spring JBoss JPA envers

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss, hibernate-envers

I have an environment with jboss 7.1.1 and spring. I use JPA for entity persistence. 
Now I also added envers. There is no problem, when I'm working with entities not annotated with @Audited. But when I try to insert an entity annotated with @Audited it doesn't work. There is an exception finishing the transaction:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at $Proxy49.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3SaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3SaveEventListener.java:71) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:642) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:635) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.revisioninfo.DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.saveRevisionData(DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.java:79) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.getCurrentRevisionData(AuditProcess.java:128) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:105) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:154) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:566) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:218) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:510) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
```

Here is my configuration of the application context:

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="catPersistence" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="de.arsinfo.cat.fwk.client.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <import resource="classpath*:bo.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.arsinfo.cat">
    </context:component-scan>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Stephan

Comment: ...it seems that the transaction is already closed at this time:Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac140a03:-12e726f:55af493c:34 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >

Comment: Please use a better title, you only had writen framework names. Maybe 'Problem persisting @Audited entity using Envers, JPA, Spring in JBoss'